# Turn off referential integrity in Derby? is it possible?

Tags: database, derby

Is there a setting in derby, for example an sql query ala "SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE" where i can turn on and off referential integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post on the mailing list (from 2006) it is not possible:

http://www.mail-archive.com/derby-user@db.apache.org/msg05345.html

I couldn't find anything in the [manual](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/ref-single.html#crefsqlj35312) either.

And the list of [jdbc parameters](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefattrib24612.html) has nothing, too.

Comment: Thank you, my solution was to switch to H2, which does support this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a constraint that you don't wish to enforce, you can use DROP CONSTRAINT to drop it.

I frequently drop a constraint for a period of time while I am re-structuring my database, then re-add the constraint subsequently when I have the new data arranged as I want it.